# How to replace spaces with underscores in sub-strings within a long string in SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace, varchar

Using SQL server 2019.

I have a VARCHAR(MAX) column with long string value. Here is part of the string:

```
'`the night is dark` as A , `the day is shining` as B , `wind moves but breeze flows` as C '

Required output is:

'`the_night_is_dark` as A , `the_day_is_shining` as B , `wind_moves_but_breeze_flows` as C '
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server, below function does the trick.
(but in case we have a very long string having quotes within substrings, this won't work)

**Logic** : we find 1st position of character, then 2nd position of its occurrence and replace the space with '_'. Change 1st position to 2nd position and continue...

```
CREATE OR ALTER FUNCTION replace_spc_with_uscore(@string VARCHAR(max)) RETURNS VARCHAR(max) as 
BEGIN

declare @max_cnt INT , @pos1 INT ,@pos2 INT = 1,@pos2_t INT = 1  , @tmp_str VARCHAR(max)=@string , @old_str VARCHAR(max) , @final_str VARCHAR(max)=@string

select  @max_cnt= len(@string) - len(replace(@string, '`', '')) 

while @max_cnt > 0 
    BEGIN
        select @pos1=CHARINDEX('`', @string , @pos2)

        select @pos2_t=CHARINDEX('`', @string , @pos1+1)

        select @pos2=CHARINDEX('`', @string , @pos1+1) - @pos1+1

        SELECT @old_str=SUBSTRING(@string,@pos1,@pos2) 
        SELECT @tmp_str=REPLACE (  SUBSTRING(@string,@pos1,@pos2)   ,' ','_')

        SELECT @final_str=REPLACE (@final_str, @old_str, @tmp_str)
        
        Select @max_cnt=@max_cnt-2  , @pos2=@pos2_t+1--@pos2+1
    END
    --select @final_str
RETURN @final_str

END
```

Hope it will help in case similar functionality is needed.